# build failed when i change my emulator version

Tags: git, react-native, git-bash

I have problem with my react native project. This project created by my senior. Yesterday, i operate in NOX and the project is installed. Today, i change my NOX to the new version, and while i operate "run-android" trouble occured. On the same day, I also tried running it on an Android Virtual Device

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.
>   Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows Daemon #0: Daemon star
>   tup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
>   does.

Answer (score 0):

I need more details to troubleshoot this.

However from the error above I feel that the problem is that the app could not find the emulator. Something might be missing in the path.

First try opening the ADB and when the ADB starts and is opertational, then run the commmand : `react-native run-android`.

If you can run the project once on android simulator then that would be perfect as It will sync and download the required gradle files and also it would add the sdk dir automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    .....
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
    }
  }
}
```